# How to access the length of a specific JSON value if I have its key

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

In this code, I want to iterate on x.Value, like x.Value[0], then x.Value[1] and so on.

```cs
...
    ...
        ...
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
        
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);
        
            foreach (var x in data)
            {
                if (x.Key.Contains(product))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x.Key.Contains(product));
                    // for (int m = 0; m <= x.Value.ToString().Length; m++)  
                }
            }
        
            Console.WriteLine(tempList.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Data not returned by Database...");
            return View();
        }
    
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: No Value recieved by client...");
        return View();
    }

    return View();
}
```

The format of my JSON file is like this...

```
{
    "BOOK": [ "FORMAT", "PAGE", "DIMENSION", "WEIGHT", "PUBLICATIONDATE", "LANGUAGE", "GENRE", "AUTHOR" ],
    "COMPUTER": [ "BRAND", "TYPE", "COLOUR", "STORAGE", "CPU", "RAM", "SCREENSIZE", "CPMPUTERTYPE", "DISPLAYTYPE", "PROCESSORCORENUMBER", "SSDSTORAGE", "PORT", "BLUETOOTH", "OPERATINGSYSTEM" ],
    "GAME": [ "FORMAT", "GENRE", "RATING", "DEVELOPER", "PUBLISHER" ],
    "MOBILE": [ "BRAND", "COLOUR", "STORAGE", "SCREENSIZE", "NETWORK", "PHONEOPERATINGSYSTEM", "SCREENSIZEINCHES", "INTERNALSTORAGE", "BATTERYCAPACITYMAH", "CPU", "RAM", "REARCAMERAMP", "FRONTCAMERAMP", "FLASH", "HEADPHONEJACK", "BLUETOOTH", "RELEASEYEAR" ],
    "MOVIE": [ "GENRE", "REGIONCODING", "RATING", "RELEASEYEAR", "FORMAT" ]
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you actually want but let me try to help you.

Let's understand your JSON schema first. It has `productCategory` ("Book","Computer","Game" etc.) and each `productCategory` has array of `properties` (For "Book" -> [ "FORMAT", "PAGE", "DIMENSION",...]

So now if you want to iterate through your productCategory and count the length of it, you can do the following:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);

            foreach (var productCategory in data)
            {
                // counts the number of properties like for eg. For "Book" it has 8 properties like "Format","Page" etc.
                var count = productCategory.Value.Children().ToList().Count;
                Console.WriteLine($"{productCategory.Key} Count: {count}");
            }
        }
```

Output:

[image]

And if you also want to iterate through properties of each productCategory, you can do the following:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);

            foreach (var productCategory in data)
            {
                // counts the number of properties like for eg. For "Book" it has 8 properties like "Format","Page" etc.
                var count = productCategory.Value.Children().ToList().Count;
                Console.WriteLine($"{productCategory.Key} Count: {count}");
                foreach (var properties in productCategory.Value)
                {
                    //Here you will have properties like "Format","Page" etc..
                    Console.WriteLine(properties);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried the idea that OhmnioX gave and played around with the code, finally created the following snippet.

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);

    foreach (var x in data)
    {
        if (x.Key.ToString().Contains(product))
        {
            var cnt =  x.Value.Children().ToList().Count;
            for (int m=0; m<=cnt-1; m++) 
            {
                tempList.Add(x.Value[m].ToString().ToUpper());
            }
        }
    }
}
```